# Update sequence based on another column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Let's say that I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id uuid unique default uuid_generate_v4(),
  version int,
  another_column text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
);
```

What I want to achieve is, when I insert new row, I want the `version` to be based on `id` column. Ex :

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+
|                  id                  | version |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
| 25d57091-4d11-40de-9ca7-2c9500eb5484 |       1 |
| 25d57091-4d11-40de-9ca7-2c9500eb5484 |       2 |
| 25d57091-4d11-40de-9ca7-2c9500eb5484 |       3 |
| 9b43eed3-92fd-40e1-9bb4-9220f6bbd7f5 |       1 |
| 9b43eed3-92fd-40e1-9bb4-9220f6bbd7f5 |       2 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

So I though about creating a sequence but couldn't find anything on this in the manual to base the nextval on a column value.

Comment: You would need to create a new sequence each time a new `id` is inserted.

Comment: There are [several questions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+sequence+based+on+column) regarding this: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821871/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239701)

Comment: Ok so, it's what I tough. I realized that an int version or a timestamp could do the same thing in my case. Thanks for the SO questions anyway !